# Change font style for column comments in SchemaCrawler

Tags: database-design, sqlalchemy, schemacrawler

Is there any way to change the font style for Column comments that are rendered to schema image?
Currently column comments assigned in SQLAlchemy using eg https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.comment
are rendered in the schema output, but has the same style as the column name and type.

For example, with the following table definition in SQLAlchemy:

```
Base = declarative_base()


class my_table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    my_column = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, comment='my column comment')

    def __init__(self, my_column):
        self.my_column = my_column
```

I run `schemacrawler.sh` with `-c schema --output-format=jpg` I get the JPG attached.
[schemacrawler example with column comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Y4d.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/) does not have a way to customize those fonts. You can create a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler) though.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)

Comment: Ok thanks. I have created a feature request. Many thanks for providing such a powerful and free library!